# Sending data into a nested Controller/View in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm messing around with JSON structures in EmberJS starting from the top level Application level and trying to pass data to a general MenuController/MenuView child so I can reuse it.

The JSON I've come up with to play around with how data gets passed through nested ember structures is this:

**JSON**

```
{
appName: "CheesyPuffs"
menuItems: [
    {name:"Gouda"}
    {name:"Crackers", menuItems: [
                              {name: "Cheezeits"}
                            ] 
    }
]

}
```

**Handlebars**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class='app'>
  <div class='header'>
     {{#if menuItems}}
    // Embed template 'menu'
     {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu">
<ul>
{{#each menuItems}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{#if menuItems}}
       // Embed menu template
     {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
App.MenuController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        click: function(){
           // Signal Event to App
        }
    }
});
App.MenuView = Ember.View.extend({

   click: function(){
        console.log("I clicked a menu");
   }

});
```

All the examples I've seen concerning nested stuff involves routes with the classic _id subroute. I'm not sure how I would go about telling the App Router that it needs to pass the menuItems data to a child controller that's embedded in the same view. I have a feeling you can do this both via the template and programmically? If so, how would you do it both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the template you should use `render`.  And that's the way you should do it, programmatically doesn't make sense.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class='app'>
  <div class='header'>
     {{#if menuItems}}
        {{render 'menu' menuItems}}
     {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu">
<ul>
{{#each menuItems}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{#if menuItems}}
        {{render 'menu' menuItems}}
     {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```